# I/O error while communicating with scanner

Tags: printer, multi-function-printer

When scanning document from windows 10 on a [Samsung Xpress M2870FD](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-m2870-laser-multifunction-printer-series/16462897) printer, it fails with

> "I/O error while communicating with the device. Please wait and try scanning again. If it does not help, please turn the device off, then switch it on and wait while it warms up."

I uninstalled the driver and installed it again, but the same error appears. The same error also appears on other PCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to download and install M2870FD software from
 [Software and driver results for: Samsung Xpress SL-M2870FD Laser Multifunction Printer](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-m2870-laser-multifunction-printer-series/16462897/model/16462695).

The section to look at is "Driver-Product Installation Software", both the
"Print Driver" and "Scan Driver".

If you are using the Easy Print Manager, open it and click "Scan to Pc Setting",
and check it is set to Enable.

If this does not help, it would help to know if you are scanning from the printer
or from the desktop, and if you are having this problem in both modes.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I installed drivers with CD which was into printer box. ok i will download and try as you advised and will inform results.

Comment: Thanks for help friend. it is solved. I did everything as you told me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A Google search for "I/O error while communicating with the device" returned [this HP Support article](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06058159). HP (which acquired Samsung's printer business some time ago) states that this is caused by a compatibility issue introduced in Windows 10 version 1803 (*Redstone 4*):

> This error message displays when the scan application is unable to recognize the changes in Windows 10 RS4.

You'll need to update your scanner software to fix this. The latest software and drivers are available [on HP's support page for your MFP](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-m2870-laser-multifunction-printer-series/16462897).